# How can I force the argument of a summation to not be offset

Tags: formatting

Right now, my summation looks like this since I have a long bottom argument:

```
$\sum\limits_{x \in A[1...i-1]} x$
```

[image]

How can I make it so that the `x` is not so offset by the bottom argument text?

Comment: Better to not use `\limits` in inline math. It causes uneven line spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve the desired effect by using the `\smashoperator` macro, which is provided by the `mathtools` package, with the `[r]` option. This informs LaTeX that an overlap should be allowed between the material placed below the summation symbol and the material that follows after the summation symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\smashoperator" macro
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
No overlap on either side
\[
y = \sum_{x \in A[1,\dots,i-1]} x
\]

\bigskip
Overlap on right-hand side only
\[  % note the option "[r]" in the following line
y = \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{x \in A[1,\dots,i-1]}} x
\]

\bigskip
Overlap on both sides
\[  
y = \smashoperator{\sum_{x \in A[1,\dots,i-1]}} x
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if `\mathrlap{...}` from `mathtools` package gives what you like to obtain:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[y=\sum\limits_{\mathrlap{x \in A[1...i-1]}} x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to allow an overlap on the right-hand side only.

Comment: yes, I apload wrong answer. I just correcting it now: instead of `\rlap` should be `\mathrlap` ...